# What is the correct term for variable shadowing in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, scope

Below we have an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) which (like any function) creates a local scope. Inside that scope there is a `parseInt` function. Now, since there already is a global function in the browser with that name, the local function will overshadow the global `parseInt` function - inside the IIFE any call to `parseInt` will call the local function, and not the global one. (The global function can still be referenced with `window.parseInt`.)

```
parseInt('123', 10); // the browser function is called

(function() {

    function parseInt() { return 'overshadowed'; }

    parseInt('123', 10); // the local function is called

})();

parseInt('123', 10); // the browser function is called
```

Is there a *de jure* (ECMAScript spec) or *de facto* (common) name for this? Overshadowing? Overloading?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The correct term is [[Variable] Shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)

> In computer programming, **variable shadowing occurs when a variable declared within a certain scope (decision block, method, or inner class) has the same name as a variable declared in an outer scope.** This outer variable is said to be shadowed...

*Functions in JavaScript are just function-objects stored within variables (or properties) that follow the same scope-chain/resolution rules as normal variables (or properties)*. This explains why the original can still be accessed as `window.parseInt` as well. It is the "IIFE" which introduces this new scope (functions are the only way to introduce new scope in JavaScript).

However, the [ECMAScript Specification [5th Edition]](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf) does not use the term *shadowing*, nor can I find a specific replacement term. (The fundamental *shadowing* behavior is defined in "10.2.2.1  GetIdentifierReference" and related sections.)

It is **not** *overloading* and it is **not** *overriding*, which are entirely different. I have no idea where *overshadowing* (in this context) originated or how it is supposed to differ from "normal" *[variable] shadowing*. If the term *shadowing* didn't already exist to explain this behavior then -- from an English language viewpoint anyway -- *overshadowing* ("to make insignificant/inconsequential") might be more appropriate than *shadowing* ("to cast shadow on/darken").

Happy coding.

Comment: `functions are the only way to introduce new scope in JavaScript` except for *with*, *eval* and *Function()*, which all modify scope.

Comment: In ES6, if/for blocks can introduce new scope, as can classes. Anyway, I think "shadow" is (much) better than "overshadow". The relevant definition is not "to cast shadow on/darken", but rather "follow (in someone's shadow)".

Answer (score 10):

If it happened by accident/mistake, you would call it [*clobbering*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clobbering) the original `parseInt()`.

Otherwise, I believe I saw it referred to *shadowing* recently here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: +1 It is just *shadowing* (term is used in C, Scala, Java, etc. dunno what lingo in Lisp-land is), although *clobbering* may feel more appropriate at times. It it **not** *overloading*.

Comment: @pst I'd say definitely if redefining `parseInt()` :)

Comment: clobbering ("overwriting its contents") would imply that you changed the value of the variable in the outer scope, so I don't believe this makes sense in this context.

Answer (score 4):

More commonly called "shadowing".