# IE8 property enumeration of replaced built-in properties (e.g. `toString`)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, properties

I've run into a very odd issue with IE8's JS engine (possibly previous versions as well, but NOT IE9 in IE8 mode since the JS engine doesn't fallback).  Simplified example:

```
var foo = { toString : 42, x : 22 };
for(var n in foo){ 
    console.log(n)
}

// result: "x"
```

In other words, the `toString` property never gets enumerated.  Nor would `valueOf`, `hasOwnProperty`, etc... or `var x = 5; x.toFixed = 42;`

So any property that natively exists can not be enumerated as far as I can tell, even after you replace it...

My question -- Does anyone know of any way to actually access these?!?  I need to because I'm walking the prototype of an object and the `toString` function isn't getting picked up.

Comment: Just a little correction: you are not replacing those inherited properties, but just *shadowing* them. I had to ask [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373278/variable-shadowing-in-javascript) to get this term right.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have IE8 anymore (at all), I would love to be able to test this for myself. What does `foo.toString` return? What does `foo.hasOwnProperty( 'toString' )` return?

Comment: @Šime Vidas - Okay, shadowing :)  `foo.toString === 42`, `foo.hasOwnProperty( 'toString' ) === true`

Comment: Found it! It's called the [JScript DontEnum Bug](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/ECMAScript_DontEnum_attribute#JScript_DontEnum_Bug).

Comment: @ŠimeVidas -- can you post an answer?  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the behavior you're experiencing in IE is the so-called "JScript DontEnum Bug" which exists in IE8 and below.

> In IE < 9, JScript will skip over any property in any object where there is a same-named property in the object's prototype chain that has the DontEnum attribute.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/ECMAScript_DontEnum_attribute#JScript_DontEnum_Bug