# Why "constructor is a special case"?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

In underscore, there is a [collectNonEnumProps](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/e4743ab712b8ab42ad4ccb48b155034d02394e4d/underscore.js#L909):

```
var nonEnumerableProps = ['valueOf', 'isPrototypeOf', 'toString',
    'propertyIsEnumerable', 'hasOwnProperty', 'toLocaleString'
];

function collectNonEnumProps(obj, keys) {
    var nonEnumIdx = nonEnumerableProps.length;
    var constructor = obj.constructor;
    var proto = (_.isFunction(constructor) && constructor.prototype) || ObjProto;

    // Constructor is a special case.
    var prop = 'constructor';
    if (_.has(obj, prop) && !_.contains(keys, prop)) keys.push(prop);

    while (nonEnumIdx--) {
        prop = nonEnumerableProps[nonEnumIdx];
        if (prop in obj && obj[prop] !== proto[prop] && !_.contains(keys, prop)) {
            keys.push(prop);
        }
    }
}
```

There is a comment say `Constrcutor is a special case`, then use `_.has(obj, prop) && !_.contains(keys, prop)` for constructor but `prop in obj && obj[prop] !== proto[prop] && !_.contains(keys, prop))` for other props which **not special**.

I had tried use `prop in obj && obj[prop] !== proto[prop] && !_.contains(keys, prop))` for `constrcutor`. Then `npm run test` everything was ok.

```
var nonEnumerableProps = ['valueOf', 'isPrototypeOf', 'toString',
    'propertyIsEnumerable', 'hasOwnProperty', 'toLocaleString', 'constructor'
];

var collectNonEnumProps = function(obj, keys) {
    var nonEnumIdx = nonEnumerableProps.length;
    var constructor = obj.constructor;
    var proto = _.isFunction(constructor) && constructor.prototype || ObjProto;


    while (nonEnumIdx--) {
        prop = nonEnumerableProps[nonEnumIdx];
        if (prop in obj && obj[prop] !== proto[prop] && !_.contains(keys, prop)) {
            keys.push(prop);
        }
    }
};
```

So, **why `underscore` treat `constrcutor` special?**

Or, it's there any differences between `_.has(obj, prop)` and `prop in obj && obj[prop] !== proto[prop]`?

Answer (score 4):

Using [git blame](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blame/e4743ab712b8ab42ad4ccb48b155034d02394e4d/underscore.js#L909) shows that it was [added in a commit](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/commit/5bfd4f9ddcf2768cedf56fb2fe621caae7833f76) with the message "Fix IE non-enumerable properties".

From there, a little more digging revealed that it is to fix this bug in IE 8 and earlier: [IE8 property enumeration of replaced built-in properties (e.g. `toString`)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7367519/772035)

Comment: Plus one for going to the source history and checkin comments.  When in doubt, go to the source Luke...

Comment: But why `toString` not special here?

Comment: Or, it's there any differences between `_.has(obj, prop)` and `prop in obj && obj[prop] !== proto[prop]`?