# Strange behaviour whith shadowing

Tags: javascript, shadowing

Although shadowing should never be used (or just to obfuscate) because it's confusing, I wanted to completely understand it. And I got this strange thing :

```
alert(parseInt('123'));//Here, I expected 123 but it's 'overshadowed'
function parseInt(){return 'overshadowed';}
alert(parseInt('123'));//Here it's 'overshadowed' too
```

Why the first `alert` output 'overshadowed' whereas the function is not modified yet?

P.S : I got inspired by [Variable shadowing in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373278/variable-shadowing-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, all declarations are *implicitly* placed at the beginning of the scope (*"hoisted"*), so it doesn't matter if the parseInt() definition was at the second, last, or first line.

Comment: It's commonly referred to as "hoisting." http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting