# how to send js function as parameter to another function?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code

```
function exec(param1,p2,fun){
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(fun){
        data=xmlhttp.responseText;
        fun(data);
    }
    // rest ajax connection code
}
```

when i call

```
 exec(param1,param2,
    function(data){
      alert (data);
    });
```

it says

> Object not a function

in the definition at line `fun('test');`

any ideas ?

Comment: Works for me... http://jsfiddle.net/jHbsW/

Comment: What does `console.log(fun)` (or `console.log(exec)`) show?

Comment: am sorry guys , its related to ajax onreadystatechange :s i updated the sample code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373278/variable-shadowing-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting `fun` with a new one in a narrower scope:

```
function exec(param1,p2,fun){
                        ^^^  - The function you pass

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(fun){
                                    ^^^ - new variable (possibly an event object)
```

Change one of the variable names so you aren't masking it inside your callback function.