# Variable is always logged as NaN

Tags: javascript

Can someone please explain to me why my `var clients` always returns `NaN` each time I try to call it with `console.log`.

```
//Imports
var inherits = require('util').inherits,
  MultiServer = require('../classes/servers/multi_server.js');
var clients = 0;

function PingServer(servers) {
  MultiServer.call(this, servers); //Inheritance

  //Basic server setup
  this.on('listen', function(params) {
    console.log("TCP server listening at", params['TCP'].ip + ":" + params['TCP'].port);
    console.log("Socket.IO server listening at", params['Socket.IO'].ip + ":" + params['Socket.IO'].port);
    console.log("All systems operational.");
  });

  this.on('error', function(err, source) {
    console.log("Error in " + source + " server:", err.message);
  });

  //Server behaviour
  this.on('connect', function(client) {
    console.log("A client has connected.");
    var clients = clients + 1;
    console.log("Client = " + clients);

    //Basic client setup
    client.on('disconnect', function() {
      console.log("A client has disconnected.");
      var clients = clients - 1;
      console.log("Clients = " + clients);
    });

    client.on('error', function(err) {
      console.log("A client has experienced an error:", err.message);
    });

    //Main server behaviour
    client.on('message', function(msg) {
      client.send(msg); //Ping reply
      console.log("Received message:", msg);
    });
  });
}
inherits(PingServer, MultiServer); //Inheritance
//Exports
module.exports = PingServer;
```

Comment: Remove all `var`s before `clients` except the first time.

Comment: try this,var clients = parseInt($(this).val()) || 0;

Comment: There are nested events in `onconnect` and declared with var keyword again in all other callbacks.

Comment: Wow... I was re-initializing the variable each time with `var`. Thanks @Xufox

Answer (score 1):

Varibles declared with `var` are function-scoped and hoisted in JavaScript. Everytime you type `var clients` it creates a variable in the scope of the current function.

This statement:

```
var clients = 0;
```

first declares the variable `clients` and then assigns it the value `0`.

Then you’re writing

```
(function(){
  var clients = clients + 1;
  console.log("Client = " + clients);
})
```

However, this does the same thing *again*: it declares a *new* variable `clients` and scopes it to the function. This new `clients` variable is *distinct* from the initial one. In this function it is *shadowed* (i.e. it cannot be accessed). Effectively, `clients` is `undefined` in the function.

Hoisting means that variable declarations are moved to the top of the function automatically.

That means the statement

```
var clients = clients + 1;
```

in the function is equivalent to

```
var clients = undefined + 1;
```

which is

```
var clients = NaN;
```

---

If, however, you removed the `var` keyword, it *wouldn’t create a new variable but instead use the old one*:

```
var clients = 0;

(function(){
  clients = clients + 1; // clients = 0 + 1 === 1;
  console.log("Client = " + clients); // "Client = 1"
})
```

And `clients = clients + 1` is probably better written as `clients++`.

---

- More on [Javascript function scoping and hoisting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7506844/4642212)
- [An example of variable shadowing in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11901427/4642212)

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple declarations for **`clients`** variable.

change this

```
var clients = clients + 1;
```

to

```
clients = clients + 1;
```

& this

```
var clients = clients - 1;
```

to

```
clients = clients - 1;
```