# My userInput does not check if seconds = 0

Tags: javascript

I have a function called userInput that checks if seconds is equal to x, then it gives an alert to the user, and then resets the time. The userInput does not check if seconds is equal to x. Should I use a for loop? Here's my code:

```
var userInput = function(x) {
  if (seconds == x) {
    var done = alert("You're done!");
    h1.textContent = "00:00:00"
    seconds = 0; minutes = 0; hours = 0;
  }
}
  userInput(x);
```

And just so you know this, seconds, minutes, and hours are already declared as variables.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: See [*How to create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You can post a runnable snippet here to display the issue.

Comment: Where is `seconds` coming from?  And, your function takes an argument called `x` but when you call `userInput` you're passing `x`.  The `x` in the function is [shadowing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901427/an-example-of-variable-shadowing-in-javascript) the `x` outside the function.

Comment: The previous question was deleted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38778172/my-userinput-function-does-not-work. It contained the rest of the code and all the context.

Comment: Ok, kevin628 fixed the issue, I was overshadowing `x`. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: `he previous question was deleted` - different user!

Answer (score -1):

I was overshadowing x in my code. Thanks for the help in the comments

Comment: Why is that a problem? You're passing `x` to the function, so it will get the same value as the outer `x`.

Comment: A good answer to a question should explain and show how to fix the problem. This answer is not useful to future readers with a similar problem.