# moment.js is visible only by one of two directives defined in the same file

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There are two directives in the same file, both directives depend on **moment.js** library. When applied the first directive (**momentNow**) sees the **moment** function and the other one doesn't (the value is **undefined**).

Both directives are used inside the same template:

**the template**

```
<datepicker date-format="yyyy-MM-dd">
    <!-- works correctly -->
    <input required ng-model="vm.dateFrom" moment-now />
</datepicker>

<datepicker date-format="yyyy-MM-dd">
    <!-- throws error -->
    <input required ng-model="vm.dateTo" moment-then />
</datepicker>
```

**the module**

```
;(function() {

    "use strict";

    angular.module('dateUtils', [])
        .directive('momentNow', momentNow)
        .directive('momentThen', momentThen);

    function momentNow() {
        return {
            /* params are omitted */
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

                console.log(moment);

                var value = moment().format(scope.momentFormat || 'YYYY-MM-DD');
                ngModel.$setViewValue(value);
                ngModel.$render();
            }
        }
    };

    function momentThen() {
        return {
            /* params are omitted */
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

                console.log(moment);

                var moment = moment();
                var format = scope.momentFormat || 'YYYY-MM-DD';
                var value = (moment.hours() >= 20 ? moment.add('days', 1) : moment).format(format);

                ngModel.$setViewValue(value);
                ngModel.$render();

            }
        }
    };

}());
```

Comment: Which of the two functions shows `moment` as "undefined"?

Comment: @GabrielLovetro The `momentThen` function. I've edited my question a little bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename your variable at this line:

```
var moment = moment();
```

You are [shadowing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901427/an-example-of-variable-shadowing-in-javascript) moment with your variable.

if you are wondering why the `console.log(moment);` show `undefined`, take a look at what is [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting).

Comment: Yes, this is it! How to explain `console.log(moment)` showing **undefined** before the `var moment = moment();` line?