# What's the difference of passing an parameter to the left-hand side as opposed to the right hand-side?

Tags: javascript

Why is it that when I do the following:

```js
var a = 1;

function foo(a) {
  a = 2;
}

foo();
console.log(a); // a = 1
```

But I get a different result for the following:

```js
var a = 1;

function foo() {
  a = 2;
}

foo();
console.log(a); // a = 2
```

Comment: search for "js global and local scopes", you'll get it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An example of variable shadowing in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901427/an-example-of-variable-shadowing-in-javascript)

Comment: Or how about a third example that's based on your second example except the `a = 2` in the function is changed to `var a = 2`?

Comment: In the first case, `a` is a parameter of the function, and thus a local variable, completely independent from the variable with the same name in the global scope. In the second case you are manipulating the variable in the global scope directly.

Comment: To be honest I think giving it a cool name like "variable shadowing" is a bit much. It makes it seem like there's more to it, but it's just scope.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, I understand that the second example behave due to scope but what has example 1 to do with scope?

Answer (score 1):

In the first example the function `foo` parameter `a` is shadowing the global variable `a` and thus the value of the global variable never changes. The code in the first example is equivalent to this one:

```
var a = 1;

function foo(x) {
  x = 2;
}
```

In the second example you are referencing the global variable `a` inside the body of the function `foo`. Here no variable shadowing occurs so that you get the expected result - `a` is asigned the value of `2`.

Answer (score 0):

if `a` is passed in as an argument to that function -- then the value of `a` within that function is isolated and only accessible within that function.  otherwise your `a` defined outside the function is shared across all functions and objects.

agree with @RomanPerekhrest -- read up.

**UPDATE in reply to comment **

```
var a = 1; 
function foo(a) { 
  a = 2;
}
foo();
console.log(a); // a = 1
```

In the code above, the reference to `a` on lines 2 and 3 are a different variable from the `a` on lines 1 and 6.  In the code from your comment, you are setting `a` to the value of `x` within the `foo` function.  That's a bit different from the original question. No?

Comment: var a = 1;    function foo(x){
  a = x;
}

foo(2);

console.log(a); // a = 2

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't really have "parameters on the left/right side." Your first example passes a parameter. Your second example uses a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)).

> In programming languages, closures (also lexical closures or function closures) are techniques for implementing lexically scoped name binding in languages with first-class functions. Operationally, a closure is a record storing a function together with an environment: a mapping associating each free variable of the function (variables that are used locally, but defined in an enclosing scope) with the value or reference to which the name was bound when the closure was created. A closure—unlike a plain function—allows the function to access those captured variables through the closure's copies of their values or references, even when the function is invoked outside their scope.

In your first example, the variable `a` inside the function `foo` is a different variable than `a` outside of the function. Changing `foo`'s parameter `a` has no effect on the global variable `a` that gets passed to `console.log`.

In your second example, the variable `a` is not a parameter, but rather a part of the environment that is captured by the function `foo`. The log shows a modified value of `a` because the assignment inside `foo` and the `console.log` call outside of `foo` are actually referring to the same variable.