# const "variable" undefined in following function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

Beginner here. Why `userName` is `undefined` in the function and how to make the function to have it as John Doe and not `undefined`?

```
const userName = 'John Doe';
console.log(userName);
const loggedInUser = (userName) => console.log('Logged in user is: ' + userName);
loggedInUser();
```

Console output:

```
index.js:22 John Doe
index.js:23 Logged in user is: undefined
```

Comment: You're hiding the "outer" `userName` with the `userName` parameter of the function.

Comment: [An example of variable shadowing in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901427/an-example-of-variable-shadowing-in-javascript)

Comment: FWIW, this is not a property, it's a "variable" though it would be more correct to say that it is a constant (since its value cannot change).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const loggedInUser = (userName) => console.log('Logged in user is: ' + userName);
```

defines a function named `loggedInUser` that takes a single argument.

After defining this function you call it on the next line `loggedInUser();`, but you don't provide the argument.

Try `loggedInUser(userName);`