# Javascript returns click function as not a function

Tags: javascript, php

I have two php files - `index.php` and `loadimages.php`.
The index page has a thumbnail gallery and a canvas.  The images to thumbnail gallery is populated through loadimages.php.  The following is the snippet of the code from loadimages.php:

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)
{
    $num = $files[$i];
    $filname = basename($num, ".jpg");
    $filnam = substr($filname, -5);
    echo '<figure class="item">';
    echo '<img class="matchImages" onclick="clickedImage(this.id)" src="'.$num.'" id="thumbNails' . $filnam . '   "/>';
        }
```

The above php code also has an onclick function `clickedImage`.  In the index.php, i have this function which is as follows:

```
function clickedImage(clicked_id) {
  localStorage.setItem("clickedImg", clicked_id);
  var clickedImg = document.getElementById(clicked_id).src;
  var clickedImg = clickedImg.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
  var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var thumbNails = document.getElementById("loaded_img_panel");
  var pic = new Image();
  pic.onload = function() {
    canvas.width = pic.width;
    canvas.height = pic.height;
    ctx.drawImage(pic, 0,0)
  }
  thumbNails.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    pic.src = event.target.src;
  });
}
```

The above code works without any errors.  I want to build in a functionality where when the page is refreshed, I want to virtually `click` on the `last clicked image` so that the user stays on the same image before reload.  I have created a eventlistener for this which is as follows:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
   var clickedImage = localStorage.getItem('clickedImg');
   clickedImage(clickedImage); 
  })
```

This is not working, and the console returns `Uncaught TypeError: clickedImage is not a function`.

Comment: `clickedImage` is not a function, because it is a value from localStorage. Seriously, how do you expect js to understand which `clickedImage` should be used in `clickedImage(clickedImage)`?

Comment: @u_mulder Since I am saving the returned imageid in localstorage, and the clickedImage function takes the imageid as an argument, I was hoping that I would be able to read them...not sure if my understanding is correct

Comment: Ok...i got the anomaly.

Comment: @u_mulder despite changing the variable name...I am still getting the same error...do you have any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Both your function and your variable are named `clickedImage`:

```
var clickedImage = localStorage.getItem('clickedImg');
clickedImage(clickedImage);
```

Rename the variable to something else (e.g. `clickedImageValue`) and you should be good to go.

The problem you experience here is called [variable shadowing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901427/an-example-of-variable-shadowing-in-javascript), by the way.

Comment: thank you for your response....I tried changing the variable name....still not working and getting the same message

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. The problem in my code was in this line within my js:

```
thumbNails.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    pic.src = event.target.src;
  });
```

Because I was invoking a click event within my function, the window.addEventListener is waiting for that click to happen.  When I changed my code to this:

```
var clkImg = localStorage.getItem('clickedImage');
  var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var thumbNails = document.getElementById("loaded_img_panel");
  var pic = new Image();
  pic.onload = function() {
    canvas.width = pic.width;
    canvas.height = pic.height;
    ctx.drawImage(pic, 0,0)
  }

  pic.src = clkImg;
```

everything started working fine.