# Javascript - variable re-delcaring in the sub-block // Variable Shadowing

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, hoisting, shadowing

I am trying to understand how Javascript handles re-declaring of the let variable in the sub-block of the current scope.

[let - JavaScript | MDN says:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)

> Variables declared by `let` have their scope in the block for which they
>   are defined, as well as in any contained sub-blocks.

If we try this, it works fine as expected:

```
function letTest() {
  let x = 1;

  for(var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    console.log(x);  // logs - 1
  }
}
```

Another example. Now I use the `for` sub-block to assign a new value to `let` variable of `0` and go through the `for` loop. 
As well this works as expected.

```
function letTest() {
  let x = 5;
  console.log(x);  // logs – 5

  for( x = 0; x < 12; x++) {
    console.log(x);  // logs – 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, … 10, 11
  }

  console.log(x);  // logs - 12
}
```

But what happens when we re-declare and assign new value to the same variable `x` by using keyword `let` inside of the `for` sub-block :

```
function letTest() {
  let x = 5;
  console.log(x);  // logs – 5

  for( let x = 0; x < 12; x++) {
    console.log(x);  // logs – 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, … 10, 11
  }

  console.log(x);  // logs - 5
}
```

What mechanism is here at work and what exactly happened?

Why is the value of `let x = 5` not changed, why is there now 2 `let` variables with the same name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found the answer here:

[Demystifying JavaScript Variable Scope and Hoisting](https://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-variable-scope-hoisting/)

> In JavaScript, variables with the same name can be specified at
>   multiple layers of nested scope. In such case local variables gain
>   priority over global variables. If you declare a local variable and a
>   global variable with the same name, the local variable will take
>   precedence when you use it inside a function. This type of behavior is
>   called shadowing. Simply put, the inner variable shadows the outer.

and here as well:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11901489/6375464

> In computer programming, variable shadowing occurs when a variable
>   declared within a certain scope (decision block, method, or inner
>   class) has the same name as a variable declared in an outer scope.
>   This outer variable is said to be shadowed...

Answer (score 1):

The **let** statement creates a block scope variable.

```
function letTest() {
  let x = 5;
  console.log(x);  // x = 5 (same 'x')

  for(let x = 0; x < 12; x++) {
    console.log(x);  // x = 1, 2, …, 10, 11 (different 'x')
  }

  console.log(x);  // x - 5 (same 'x')
}
```

while **var** statement creates a function scope variable.

```
function varTest() {
  var x = 5;
  console.log(x);  // x = 5

  for(var x = 0; x < 12; x++) {
    console.log(x);  // x = 1, 2, …, 10, 11
  }

  console.log(x);  // x = 12 ('x' from the for-loop)
}
```

Comment: yes but what mechanism is here at work, the same variable with x=5 has a scope inside the for loop, os what happens once we redeclare it inside of the for loop. How do they coexist together?

Comment: The result should be 11 and not 12

Comment: 'x' is supposed to be 12, since the for-loop incremented x to 12 (which is not smaller than 12). Therefore we left the for-loop.