# forEach to mimic .map() function

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I am trying to mimic `array.map()` using forEach().

```
var map = function () {
  var empMap = [];
  numbers.forEach(function (number) {
    empMap.push(number);
    console.log('empMap', empMap);
  });
  return(empMap);
}

var numbers = [1, 2, 3];
//implement this line

var doubles = map(numbers, function (number) {
  return number * 2;
});
console.log(doubles); // [2, 4, 6]
```

So, I have this `numbers` array with values and I have my own `map function` to iterate through the array and then I pushing the values in an empty array `empMap`

later, I am calling this map function and multiplying each value with 2 and printing it out.

I should get the output of doubles as [2, 4, 6] instead I am getting [1,2,3]. Not sure where I going wrong.

This is the [[codepen][1](https://codepen.io/ntanwir10/pen/WPoZWN?editors=0012)](https://codepen.io/ntanwir10/pen/WPoZWN?editors=0012) for the same.

Comment: You don't capture the arguments for use in your definition of map, so...

Comment: pass arguments to your funcion. Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass the array and the callback as arguments and then actually use the callback.

```js
var map = function (array, callback) {
  var empMap = [];

  array.forEach(function (number) {
    empMap.push(callback(number))
  });

  return(empMap);
}

var numbers = [1, 2, 3];

var doubles = map(numbers, function (number) {
  return number * 2;
});

console.log(doubles); // [2, 4, 6]
```

Comment: Minor quibble - you're using the name `numbers` twice in the same scope, would be better to change one of them to avoid shadowing.

Comment: I intentionally avoid changing the OP as much as possible, instead opting to only tweak what's necessary. OP should [take a note](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901427/an-example-of-variable-shadowing-in-javascript) of your comment though.