# JavaScript for loop with let

Tags: javascript, let

My JavaScript book, "JavaScript The Definitive Guide, 6th Ed.", page 270 includes this text and code:

*"... in a for loop, the initializer expression is evaluated
outside the scope of the new variable"*

```
let x = 1;
for (let x = x + 1; x < 5; x++) {
    console.log(x); // prints 2, 3, 4
}
```

When I run the above code (in the latest version of Chrome and FF) however, I get console errors:

> ReferenceError: x is not defined
>
> can't access lexical declaration `x' before initialization

Is the code in the book incorrect? (There's nothing on the book's errata site re: this.)

Comment: `x` is being **redeclared**, that's the issue.

Comment: @briosheje no, it doesn't get redeclared. It gets shadowed.

Comment: @JonasWilms true, indeed. Though the issue is still there. It's shadowed by the local `x` variable, right?

Comment: @briosheje the issue is trying to access a variable inside of its initializer. The quoted paragraph is just wrong.

Comment: Thanks everyone!  This is making more sense to me now.  I now have a MUCH better understanding of how the keyword let behaves!

Answer (score 5):

The problem is not really that `x` gets declared twice. It is just that you are trying to access the inner `x` before it got initialized:

```
 let x = x /* doesn't exist yet*/;
```

Wether there is another `x` in the outer scope (initializers in a `for` loop are inside their own scope) doesn't matter, the `x` will refer to the variable in the current scope, as it already got declared (due to hoisting), but wasn't initialized yet:

```
 let x = 0; // irrelevant

 { // x gets declared as part of this scope
   x; // thats an error too as x is not initialized yet
   let x = 1; // initialization
   x; // now it can be accessed
 }
```

The part between the beginning of a scope and a `let` declaration is called the "temporal dead zone" ...

> "... in a for loop, the initializer expression is evaluated outside the scope of the new variable"

No, otherwise you couldn't refer to other variables in the initializer:

```
 for(let a = 1, b = a; ; )
```

As always, the definite answer can be found in the spec:

> **13.7.4.7 Runtime Semantics: LabelledEvaluation**
>
> IterationStatement : for ( LexicalDeclaration Expression ; Expression ) Statement
>
> 1. Let oldEnv be the running execution context's LexicalEnvironment.
> 2. Let loopEnv be NewDeclarativeEnvironment(oldEnv).
>
> [...]
>
> 5. Let boundNames be the BoundNames of LexicalDeclaration.
> 6. For each element dn of boundNames [..]
>
>    Perform ! loopEnvRec.CreateImmutableBinding(dn, true).
> 7. Set the running execution context's LexicalEnvironment to loopEnv.
> 8. Let forDcl be the result of evaluating LexicalDeclaration.
>
> [...]

As you can see, the running execution context is `loopEnv` while the LexicalDeclaration (the initializers) gets evaluated, not `oldEnv`.

TLDR: Not only the example is wrong, but also the paragraph.

Answer (score 4):

The only issue is that `x` is being <strike>**redeclared**</strike> **shadowed** (as mentioned by Jonas above), hence it throws an error.

Just remove the second `let` and everything will work as expected.

```
let x = 1;
for (x = x + 1; x < 5; x++) {
   //^---- note the missing "let" here. 
   console.log(x); // prints 2, 3, 4
}
```

If you copied that from a book, then that's a book issue.

https://jsfiddle.net/hto9udmj/

Further infos about variable declarations can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Further infos about variables shadowing: 
[An example of variable shadowing in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901427/an-example-of-variable-shadowing-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

> Is the code in the book incorrect? (There's nothing on the book's errata site re: this.)

I believe the books *was* correct; when `let` was introduced for the first time years ago in Firefox.

Specifically, it didn't have the [temporal dead zone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Temporal_dead_zone), and it behaves internally more like `var`, just block scoped.

In Firefox 44, there was a breaking change that makes `let` and `const` following the standards:

https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2015/10/14/breaking-changes-let-const-firefox-nightly-44/

Including the introduction of the temporal dead zone.

So, yes, the book *now* is incorrect; since you're trying to do something like:

```
let x = 0;
{
  let y = x; // `let` is block-scope,
             // so this `x` is actually the `x` 
             // defined below, not the one outside
             // the scope, hence the `ReferenceError`.
  let x = 1;
}
```

Comment: Without the temporal deadzone it `for(let x = x` would just be `undefined`, the evaluation of for loop initializers must have changed too

Comment: As said, `let` was just seen internally like a `var` with some block-scope functionality. Specifically, in the case of the loop, `let x = x + 1` would have taken the `x` (of `x + 1`) from outside the scope, because it wasn't declared yet. I'm not saying that is a good behavior, I'm just saying this is how the first implementation of `let` was working. You can test yourself with a version of Firefox that implements the "legacy" `let`: in that case, the code in the book was "correct" (in the sense that works as the book specify).

Answer (score 2):

You are initializing x twice and thus getting error. Rename one x to i

```js
let x = 1;
for (let i = x + 1; i < 5; i++) {
    console.log(i); // prints 2, 3, 4
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you redeclare `x` within the `for` loop and since `let` only exists within the given context, after the loop is done `x` doesn't exist anymore.

Either declare `x` once outside of the `for` loop, or use `var`. `var` adds the variable to a global scope, so it'll exist after the `for` loop is done.

```js
let x = 1;
for (x = x + 1; x < 5; x++) {}
console.log(x);
```

With var:

```js
for (var x = 2; x < 5; x++) {}
console.log(x);
```