# Function, Global Variable, and Local Variable

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I can't understand why the x after test won't become 30 but still remains 10

```
  <script>
        function test(){
            var x = 30;
            y = 40;
        }
    </script>


    <script>
        var x = 10;
        var y = 20;

        document.write("before test, x: " + x + ", y: " + y + "<br/><br/>");

        test();

        document.write("after test, x: " + x + ", y: " + y + "<br/><br/>");

    </script>
```

Comment: You create a local x inside the test() function, but edit the global y.

Comment: @Quentin This isn't really about what "var" means. It is about variable shadowing. Those are two very different things to a beginner.

Comment: @MY_Chen Since I can't leave an answer, I'll just mention it here. This is known as variable shadowing and also has to do with scope. This question talks about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901427/an-example-of-variable-shadowing-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

This is because by declaring `var x = 30;`, you create a variable named `x` that exists only in the function's scope.

The variable `y`, however, is only defined at top-level. So when you run the function `test`, you edit the local `x` variable, and the global (top-level) `y` variable.

Answer (score 0):

When you define variables they are hoisted at top of its scope. Let me show you how your current code:

```
function test(){
  var x = 30;
  y = 40;
}
var x = 10;
var y = 20;
test();
```

Will run like this:

```
// global scope
var x; // x is undefined
var y; // y is undefined
function test() {
  // function scope
  var x; // x is undefined inside this scope
  x = 30; // x is assigned with value 30
  y = 40; // y is assigned with value 40
  // the global scope y value is assigned
}
x = 10; // x is assigned with value 10
// the global scope x value is assigned
y = 20; // y is assigned with value 20
// the global scope y value is assigned
test();
// when calling test,
// you see x is assigned with its function scope
// and y is assigned with its global scope
// so, at this point
// x becomes 10
// y becomes 40
```

---

You can read more about `var` here in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var). Also, look in the [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope), [global scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_scope) and [local scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Local_scope).

---

Also, note that [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) and [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) works differently. They are scoped in the block. You can read them in the corresponding links which are linked here in.

Comment: This post was marked as duplicate. But I had to provide my explanation on this. So, re-opened the post and marked as duplicate again. Sorry for this!