# Why assigning 'null' to a variable before using it, sometimes

Tags: javascript, function, null, p5.js

Taking the following code snippet as an example:

```js
//variable a,b and c will hold Constructors later
var a = null;
var b = null;
var c;

function setup() {
  //assign those Constructors to variable a,b and c
  a = new ControlsAndInput();
  b = new p5.FFT();
  c = new myOwnConstructor();
}
```

I noticed some people like to declare and assign the `null` value to a global variable which will be used later.

**The question is:** what's the differences between assigning a `null` value and not assigning a `null` value to a variable before using it? Is there any difference between var `a`,`b` and `c` in above example, such that unlike `a` and `b`, `c` was not assigned a `null` value at the start, could this cause any potential bug, why I need to assign `null` to a variable before using it sometimes

Comment: If the variable isn't used before it's assigned to for real, it's pointless.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55165242/function-global-variable-and-local-variable/55165598#55165598

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you don't assign `null` to a variable you "assign" `undefined` to it.

```
var a = null;
var b = null;
var c;

console.log(a, b, c) // => null, null, undefined
```

You can read answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076944/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-undefined-in-javascript) if you want to know the difference between `null` and `undefined`.

If you're curious why people want to add `null` instead of having `undefined` - there might be reasons. For example, to pass `undefined` check in the code. Also, sometimes people can assign not null, but initial values, like `false`, `0`, `''`, etc; it is a similar action.

But in your particular case you can just use `var a, b, c;` and it will work and doesn't break any rules.

Answer (score 1):

What you are essentially doing is saving global variables for later reassignment inside a function. There's no real difference between `null` and `undefined` (except that `null` is an object and `undefined` is `undefined`).

Your variables currently look like:

```js
var a = null;
var b = null;
var c;

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
console.log(c);
```

The simpler way to do this would be to just assign them all at once without a value:

```
var a, b, c;
```

Then you can reassign all those as you wish later.

Comment: “null is an object”..? Doesn’t seem correct. Anyway that would be precisely the difference, assuming that some code made a distinction between the two different values before re-assignment. (And not accessed prior the initial value is .. moot.)

Comment: It is! `typeof null === "object"`.

Comment: So you just rephrase my answer?

Comment: `null` is actually a primitive, it is a well-known bug that `typeof null` evaluates to `"object"`, but it would break to much code to fix it. The joys of javascript. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808226/why-is-typeof-null-object

Answer (score 1):

It's an opinion based question. In most cases, you'll assign them with undefined value. And in some cases, you may use `null` which is to check if the variable is not undefined. But be aware that [null is evil](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12777/are-null-references-really-a-bad-thing).

Now, let me clarify why we need like that?

```
var a; // undefined
function setup() {
  a = 10;
}
console.log(a); // a is still undefined
setup();
console.log(a); // a is now 10
```

So, you are just defining the variable a outside the function scope and assigning its value in the required setup. And whenever you'll call the function the global scope variable is being updated.

Hope this makes sense now.