# access variable in fadeout callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I access `test` inside the `fadeOut()` callback?

```
  slide(test) {
    console.log("test before callback: ", test);
    $(".class").fadeOut(1000, function(test) {
      console.log("test after callback: ", test);
    });
  }
```

slide()

```
test before callback:  Proxy {dispatchConfig: {…}, _targetInst: ReactDOMComponent, isDefaultPrevented: ƒ, isPropagationStopped: ƒ, _dispatchListeners: ƒ, …}
45my.js:17 test after callback:  undefined
```

Comment: Remove the `test` from the fadeOut callback parameters

Comment: i.e.: `$(".class").fadeOut(1000, function() { console.log(test); }`

Answer (score 0):

Remove `test` from the callback parameter as that is shadowing your outer most `test` argument.

View this question for a bit about shadowing in JavaScript [An example of variable shadowing in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901427/an-example-of-variable-shadowing-in-javascript)