# Why is this 'feelings' showing up as an object instead of what I enter in the textfield?a

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

- when I console.log(feelings) it prints the inputted text value in the
  form.
- However when I try to add 'feelings' to the object and update
  the ui with it I get [object Object]
- when you use feelings.value down
  in the async code it works just fine. isn't feelings.value ===
  .value.value??

```
<div class ="holder zip">
    <label for="zip">Enter Zipcode here</label>
    <input type="text" id="zip" placeholder="enter zip code here">
  </div>
  <div class ="holder feel">
    <label for="feelings">How are you feeling today?</label>
    <textarea class= "myInput" id="feelings" placeholder="Enter your feelings here" rows="9" cols="50"></textarea>
    <button id="generate" type = "submit"> Generate </button>
  </div>

    function generate (e) {
      const zipcode = document.querySelector('#zip').value;
      const feelings = document.querySelector('#feelings').value;
      console.log(zipcode)
      console.log(feelings)
    
      getWeather(baseURL+zipcode+apiKey)
      .then(function(data){
        postData(data)
      })
      .then(updateUI)
    }
    /* Function to GET Web API Data*/
    const getWeather = async (url = '') => {
      const response = await fetch(url);
    
      try {
        const weatherData = await response.json();
        weatherData['date'] = newDate; 
        weatherData['feelings'] = feelings; //where it displays as an {} unless use feelings.value
        console.log(weatherData);
        return weatherData;
    
      } catch(error){
        console.log('error', error);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Excuse me, its only working when I used...

Comment: const feelings = document.querySelector('#feelings');

and then further down i use feelings.value

Comment: it is not however working when i just use 
const feelings = document.querySelector('#feelings').value ;

and then further down I just try to use 'feelings' and it returns [object Object]

Comment: `feelings` in `getWeather` is not in the  same scope as the code within `generate`, so it defaults to `window.feelings` since you don't have it scoped off, which in most Browser's will be the same as `document.getElementById('feelings')`. Don't use that first syntax when accessing Elements by HTML id in the real world.

Comment: oh man, haha thank you! yes this is totally a silly mistake.  You are saying document.getElementByID('feelings') > document.querySelector('#feelings') ?

thanks again

Comment: @ChrisCunningham no, `document.getElementByID('feelings')` is the same as `document.querySelector('#feelings')`. The problem is that your browser already created a variable called `feelings` which is the dom element

Comment: The thing about keeping it local in this case is that the Element is gotten every time `generate` fires. Why get the Element again and again, when you can just get it once?... and *NO* on your question @ChrisCunningham, I'm saying `feelings` by itself is the same as those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`feelings` is not just any random object, it's your `textarea` element. This weird behavior is a bad feature of chrome and some other browsers; they assign DOM elements with ids to global variables named after the ids, read more about it on this other SO question: [Do DOM tree elements with ids become global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3434278/9867451)

Since you're not passing `feelings` from `generate` to `getWeather`, the `feelings` used is the global variable created by the browser which is the DOM element, an object. In other words, the global variable `feelings` is not [**shadowed**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11901427/9867451), so it is used.

To fix this, simply pass `feelings` as an argument from `generate` to `getWeather` like so:

```
function generate (e) {
  //...
  getWeather(baseURL + zipcode + apiKey, feelings)
  // ...
}

const getWeather = async (url, feelings) => {
  // here the parameter 'feelings' is used rather than the global variable 'feelings'.
}
```

Comment: Personally, I would just put `const feelings = document.querySelector('#feelings');` above `generate`, unless the Element has some kind of dynamic constraints.

Comment: @ChrisCunningham You're welcome! Glad I could help : )

Comment: @StackSlave keeping things local is better, no need to pollute the global scope. Besides, `generate` is probably used as an event listener, so caching the value won't work as expected

Comment: yes, so actually when I jsut moved it to global scope some weird behavior was happening again, and I think this is why I moved it into generate in the first place

Comment: @ChrisCunningham exactly. You should keep it inside and pass it as an argument like I showed you

Comment: Oh my gosh this is so relieving, so what youre saying is the feelings.value originally wasnt even using the feelings I had declared, it was using the one the browser created globally, and the name was coincidentally the same name as my declaration so it was hiding its origin from me!

Comment: @ChrisCunningham yes

Comment: Oops, I thought I posted this here: 
The thing about keeping it local in this case is that the Element is gotten every time generate fires. Why get the Element again and again, when you can just get it once?

Comment: @StackSlave I just noticed that you didn't use `.value` in your comment, I thought you're storing the value. Caching the element totally makes sense, although nowadays, it hardly makes a difference because everything happens so fast anyway.