# Changing an array item creates an unlimited nested copy of itself?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to set a number in an input field and keep it in a state. However when I try to set the state of the array, it doesn't get populated and when I try it with an anonymous function it creates something like

```
{
    "btm": {
        "btm": {
            "btm": {...}, 
            "top": 100}, 
        "top": 100}, 
    "top": 100
}
```

Here the code that does this:

```
const Numbers = (props) => {
    const [numbers, setNumbers] = useState({"btm": "1", "top": "100"});
    
    const fromNumber = (n) => {
        console.log(numbers);
        setNumbers((n) => {
            const copy = numbers;
            copy["btm"] = n;
            return copy;
        });
    }

return (
            <>
                <input variant="toolbar-input" defaultValue={numbers["btm"]} onChange={e => fromNumber(e.target.value)} />
            </>
);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using useState, you can do:

```
const Numbers = (props) => {
  const [numbers, setNumbers] = useState({ btm: "1", top: "100" });

  const fromNumber = (n) => {
    console.log(numbers);
    setNumbers({...numbers, btm: n});
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input
        variant="toolbar-input"
        defaultValue={numbers["btm"]}
        onChange={(e) => fromNumber(e.target.value)}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

Note that a map has unique keys, so you can go on with ES6 Spread Syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You are overriding the variable `n` here.

```
const fromNumber = (n) => {
  console.log(numbers);
  setNumbers((n) => {
    const copy = numbers;
    copy["btm"] = n;
    return copy;
  });
}
```

Here `n` is a value received from the input:

```
const fromNumber = (n) => {
```

Here `n` is the previous state of variable `numbers`:

```
setNumbers((n) => {
```

So you are nesting older state in the new one.

Comment: For more information: see this question on [shadowing in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901427/an-example-of-variable-shadowing-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same variable name here - `const fromNumber = (n) => {...` and here `setNumbers((n) => {...`.

Also you can go with ES6 Spread Syntax and convert state update function to this:

```
setNumbers((prevNumbers) => ({
   ...prevNumbers,
   btm: n,
}));
```