# Range Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, closures, higher-order-functions

I'm creating a function saveOutput that accepts a function, and a string. `saveOutput` will then return a function that behaves exactly like the passed-in function, except for when the password string is passed in as an argument. When this happens, the returned function will return an object with all previously passed-in arguments as keys, and the corresponding outputs as values.

I think my code below is correct but I run into the `Range Error: Maxiumum call stack size exceeded` when I run my code.

```
   function saveOutput(inputFunc, string) {
      let obj = {};
      //inputFunc() accepts one args
      //string like a pwd
     return function inputFunc(input) {
        if (input === string) {
            return obj;
             } else {
            obj[input] = inputFunc(input);
            return inputFunc(input);
        }
      }
      //returns a fxn
      return inputFunc;
   }

    //Test cases
    const multiplyBy2 = function(num) { return num * 2; };
    const multBy2AndLog = saveOutput(multiplyBy2, 'boo');
    console.log(multBy2AndLog(2)); // should log: 4
    console.log(multBy2AndLog(9)); // should log: 18
    console.log(multBy2AndLog('boo')); // should log: { 2: 4, 9: 18 }
```

Comment: You're shadowing the argument `inputFunc` by defining a function with the same name. Use just `return function (input) { .. }` or, if you want to give this function a name, use any other name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the name `inputFunc` twice. The returned function is called `inputFunc` so it shadows the callback function passed as parameter. The returned function calls `inputFunc` which is itself and causes an endless recursion and eventually the "maxiumum call stack size exceeded" error is thrown.

To fix this either use a different name or make it anonymous as the name is not needed anyway, here is the working code with some improvements:

```
function saveOutput(inputFunc, string) {
  let obj = {};

  return function (input) {                    // make it anonymous
    if (input === string) {
      return obj;
    }
                                               // improvement 1: the else block can be omitted here
    return obj[input] = inputFunc(input);      // improvement 2: no need to call inputFunc twice, just assign and return at the same time 
  }

  // the return statement here is never reached because there is a return right before it so just remove it
}
```

Read more about variable shadowing here: [An example of variable shadowing in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11901427/9867451)

**Demo:**

```js
function saveOutput(inputFunc, string) {
  let obj = {};

  return function(input) {
    if (input === string) {
      return obj;
    }

    return obj[input] = inputFunc(input);
  }
}

const multiplyBy2 = function(num) {
  return num * 2;
};
const multBy2AndLog = saveOutput(multiplyBy2, 'boo');
console.log(multBy2AndLog(2));
console.log(multBy2AndLog(9));
console.log(multBy2AndLog('boo'));
```