# How to resolve ' ' is already declared in the upper scope in reactproject.test.js files?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, react-testing-library

Im facing this issue in Sonarqube after pushing my code
How to resolve this issue?

** App.test.js**

```
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import App from "./App";
import { Router } from "react-router-dom"
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import { createHashHistory as createHistory } from 'history';
const mockStore = configureStore([]); 
const initialState = {
  login: {
    access: "access123",
    refresh: "refresh123"
  },
  menu: {
    data: [
      {
        id: 'home',
        title: 'Home',
        isTvFocus: true,
        isActive: true
      },
      {
        id: 'mylist',
        title: 'My list',
        isTvFocus: false,
        isActive: false
      },
      {
        id: 'search',
        title: 'Search',
        isTvFocus: false,
        isActive: false
      }
    ]
  },
}
const store = mockStore(initialState);
export const renderWithState = (
  ui,
  { initialState, ...renderOptions } = {}
```

> 'initialState' is already declared in the upper scope.Why is this an issue?

```
) => {
  const history = createHistory();
  const Wrapper = ({ children }) => (
    <Provider store={store}><Router history={history}>{children}</Router></Provider>
  );
  return render(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper, ...renderOptions });
};
jest.mock('./components/Menu',() => () => <div data-testid="menu-id">Home</div> )
test("renders app component with state", () => {
  const { getByText, getByTestId } = renderWithState(<App />, { initialState });
  screen.debug();
  expect(getByText(/Home/i).textContent).toBe("Home");
  expect(getByTestId(/menu-id/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
  fireEvent.keyDown(getByText(/Home/i), {
    key: "ArrowRight",
    code: "ArrowRight",
    keyCode: 39,
    charCode: 39
  });
  const actions = store.getActions();
  const rightAction = actions.filter(obj => obj.type==='RIGHT')
  expect(rightAction.length).toEqual(1);
});
it('Should call storeToken', () => {
  // const { storeToken } = renderWithState(<App />, { initialState });
  // screen.debug();
  const res = App.storeToken()
  console.log('red', res);
  // expect(App.storeToken).toBeTruthy();
  // let node = shallow(<App />);
  // const getPhoneCompSpy = jest.spyOn(node.instance(), 'storeToken');
  // expect(getPhoneCompSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

similar error in menu.test.js

** Menu.test.js **

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { Router } from "react-router-dom"
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import { createHashHistory as createHistory } from 'history';
import Menu from "./Menu"
const mockStore = configureStore([]);
const initialState = {
    login: {
        access: "access123",
        refresh: "refresh123"
    },
    menu: {},
}
const menu = {
    data: [
        {
            id: 'home',
            title: 'Home',
            isTvFocus: true,
            isActive: true
        },
        {
            id: 'mylist',
            title: 'My list',
            isTvFocus: false,
            isActive: false
        },
        {
            id: 'search',
            title: 'Search',
            isTvFocus: false,
            isActive: false
        }
    ]
}
const store = mockStore(initialState);
export const renderWithState = (
    ui,
    { initialState, ...renderOptions } = {}
```

> 'initialState' is already declared in the upper scope.Why is this an issue?

```
) => {
    const history = createHistory();
    const Wrapper = ({ children }) => (
        <Provider store={store}><Router history={history}>{children}</Router></Provider>
    );
    return render(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper, ...renderOptions });
};
jest.mock("teplay-ui/Components/Collection/TvMenu", () => {
    return {
        TvMenu: () => {
            return <div data-testid="tvMenu">Home</div>;
        }
    };
});
test("renders Menu component with initial state", () => {
    const { getByText, getByTestId } = renderWithState(<Menu />, { initialState });
    screen.debug();
    expect(getByText(/Home/i).textContent).toBe("Home");
    expect(getByTestId(/tvMenu/)).toBeInTheDocument();
});
test("renders Menu component with menu props", () => {
    initialState.menu = menu
    const { getByText, getByTestId } = renderWithState(<Menu />, { initialState });
    screen.debug();
    expect(getByText(/Home/i).textContent).toBe("Home");
    expect(getByTestId(/tvMenu/)).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

what could possibly be the reason ?

Comment: It is telling you that you should not use same variable names in a scope (and its inner scope). Your JS code will work because of variable [shadowing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11901482/2873538). To avoid this warning, you can give the inner variable a new name when destructuring : `{ initialState: someStateName, ...renderOptions } = {}`