# TypeError: Date.getFullYear is not a function on ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, typeerror

I am trying to add a dynamic list to my Expanse List and am getting this error while doing it:

```
**TypeError: Date.getFullYear is not a function**

[TypeError: Date.getFullYear is not a function on ReactJs ][1]
```

but in a static list, it shows me the format as I wanted with no error.

This is a static list:

[image: This is a static list]

I am trying to update the list depending on user input.

**Expanse.js**

```
  return (
    <div>
      <Wrapper>
        <DateAndTitle>
          <ExpanseTime>
            <ExpanseDates Date={date} />
          </ExpanseTime>
          <Title>{title}</Title>
        </DateAndTitle>
        <Amount>{amount}$</Amount>
      </Wrapper>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**ExpanseDate.js**

```
  let month =Date.toLocaleString("en-US", { day: "2-digit" });
  let day = Date.toLocaleString("en-US", { month: "long" });
  let year = Date.getFullYear();


  return (
    <Wrapper>
     <ExpanseDays>{day}</ExpanseDays>
      <ExpanseMonth>{month}</ExpanseMonth>
      <ExpanseYear>{year}</ExpanseYear>

    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```

**AddExpanse.js**

This is User Input:

[image: This is User Input]

**The is userInput code :**

[image]

Comment: Incidentally, your `month` and `day` variables are misnamed for each other's values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

You still haven't provided a reproducible example or all of the dependent code in your app, but now I think that you are passing a [`string`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) to the `Date` property of your `ExpanseDates` component instead of an actual [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

If you are using a [date input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) to get a date value, you'll need to parse the `value` of the input into an actual JavaScript date object before passing it to that component:

```js
function getDateFromInput (input) {
  const [y, m, d] = input.value.split('-').map(s => parseInt(s, 10));
  return new Date(y, m - 1, d);
}

function handleChange (ev) {
  const date = getDateFromInput(ev.target);
  // use the date: just logging it to console here
  console.log(date.toString());
}

document.querySelector('input[type="date"]').addEventListener('input', handleChange);
```

```html
<input type="date" value="1999-12-31" />
```

---

The example you've shown is incomplete and can't be used to reproduce your error. However, here's a snippet which includes relevant portions in your question, demonstrating how to destructure a value from a component's `props`:

In the case of your code, the property's name happens to be `Date`, which is the same name as the builtin [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) class in JavaScript and [shadows it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11901427/438273) in the scope of the component. **This is generally not a good practice: it's not a good idea to shadow built-ins.**

Try renaming that prop in your `ExpanseDates` component to avoid ambiguity with the builtin `Date`.

```html
<div id="root"></div><script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.16.4/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" data-type="module" data-presets="react">

function Component (props) {
  const {Date} = props;
  let day = Date.toLocaleString("en-US", { day: "2-digit" });
  let month = Date.toLocaleString("en-US", { month: "long" });
  let year = Date.getFullYear();
  return <div>{year} {month} {day}</div>;
}

function Example () {
  const date = new Date();
  return <Component Date={date} />;
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));

</script>
```

Comment: yes i did your suggestion but some how i still get **TypeError: Date.getFullYear is not a function**
here is the error : https://imgur.com/a/2lyb5TN

Comment: @Oulili It looks like you still haven't renamed that property on your component's `props`. Try changing the name from `Date` to `date` (lowercase `d`).

Comment: Thanks For answering yea i change it to d lowecase the static page shows me this: https://imgur.com/a/8MKbEVl  , it's means it's working but when i hit submite button it's gives me : date.getFullyear() is not a function i texted on on twitter if you want all souce code

Comment: We can't help you debug without a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: okay i will try

Comment: @Oulili See my updated answer.

Comment: Hi again i find the problem when i useState to store data from user input in an object it's was like this obj ={ date = dateex} i forget to parse the date using date:new Date (datexx)

Answer (score 1):

/***
even though an input element attribute has date type, it always returns a string value,
So, inside your Form component, you must first convert the entered input string date  to this date format 'Sun Dec 05 1999 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)'.
**Reason** : in some DateComponent, that input value is considered as date and you have applied Date object's related method. ex: [inputDate.toLocaleString("en-US", { month: "long" })]
**/

/**form component****/

```
const defaultUserInput = {
  title: "",
  amount: "",
  date: "",
};


const ExpenseForm = ({ onSaveExpenseData }) => {
    
    const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState(defaultUserInput);
    const { title, date, amount } = userInput;
  
    const changeHandler = (event) => {
      const { value, name } = event.target;
  
      setUserInput((prevState) => {
        if (name === "date") {
          const [y, m, d] = value.split("-").map((s) => parseInt(s, 10));
          return { ...prevState, [name]: new Date(y, m - 1, d) };
        }
        return { ...prevState, [name]: value };
      });
    };
  
    const SubmitHandler = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      onSaveExpenseData(userInput);
      setUserInput(defaultUserInput);
    };
  
    return (
      <form onSubmit={SubmitHandler}>
        <div className="new-expense__controls">
          <div className="new-expense__control">
            <label>Title</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              onChange={changeHandler}
              name="title"
              value={title}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="new-expense__control">
            <label>Amount</label>
            <input
              type="number"
              min="0.01"
              step="0.01"
              onChange={changeHandler}
              name="amount"
              value={amount}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="new-expense__control">
            <label>Amount</label>
            <input
              type="date"
              min="2019-01-01"
              max="2022-01-01"
              onChange={changeHandler}
              name="date"
              value={date}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
  
        <div className="new-expense__actions">
          <button type="submit">Add Expense</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  };
  
  export default ExpenseForm;
```

/**date component****/

```
const ExpenseDate = ({ date }) => {
   
  const month = date.toLocaleString("en-US", { month: "long" });

  const Itemdate = date.toLocaleString("en-US", { day: "2-digit" });

  const year = date.getFullYear();

  return (
    <div className="expense-date">
      <div className="expense-date__month">{month}</div>
      <div className="expense-date__day">{Itemdate}</div>
      <div className="expense-date__year">{year}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ExpenseDate;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const [dateUpdate, setDateUpdate] = useState("");
const [nameUpdate, setNameUpdate] = useState("");
const [priceUpdate, setPriceUpdate] = useState("");     

//In function (it might be your submit button in your form component)

const dataShow = {
      title: nameUpdate,
      amount: priceUpdate,
      date: new Date(dateUpdate),
    };

//Make sure you use new Date(dateUpdate) instead of date: dateUpdate
```

Comment: Make sure you use new Date(dateUpdate) instead of date: dateUpdate,

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const now = new Date();
let month = now.toLocaleString("en-US", { day: "2-digit" });
let day = now.toLocaleString("en-US", { month: "long" });
let year = now.getFullYear();
```

Comment: this what it's gives me : \https://imgur.com/a/AEniOk4