# jQuery typeerror object not a function when grabbing a value from label

Tags: jquery, function, object, typeerror

I am trying to simply get a value from a label with an id.
I have jQuery experience, but cannot figure out why I keep getting a "Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function" error on the first line of the script.

Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <label id="test">Value</label>
    </div>
    <script>
        jQuery(window).load(function ($) {
            var label = $('#test');
            var prev = label.text();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument received by [`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)'s callback is an event object:

```
jQuery(window).load(function ($) {
//                            ^ receives a jQuery event object
```

You may be confusing it with the [DOM Ready handler](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) which receives `jQuery` as the first parameter:

```
//both of these would have $ as an alias for jQuery:
jQuery(document).ready(function($){});
jQuery(function($){});
```

---

Back to the issue, there are three ways to fix it.

First, in case `$` is in the global scope, you can easily solve the issue by removing/renaming the `$` parameter from your `.load` callback which is [shadowing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5373278/1331430) the global `$`.

Otherwise, in case jQuery is in [`noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) mode, you can use an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) wrapper to manually alias `$`:

```
(function($) { //aliases jQuery to $ inside this scope
    $(window).load(function() {
        //$ references jQuery in inner scopes too as long as you don't shadow it
        var label = $('#test');
        var prev = label.text();
    });
}(jQuery));
```

And as a 3rd option, in case you don't need to wait for `window`'s `load` event, just use a DOM Ready handler instead. The `ready` handler fires earlier (as soon as the DOM structure is ready) while the `window`'s `.load` has to wait for all resources to load first (including images).

Most of the time `.ready()` is enough and doesn't make the user wait until the last image has loaded before interacting with your page. Now if you're working with images' dimensions or something similar, `$(window).load()` may be more interesting. Experiment and see.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to pass `$` as an argument to your function. Doing this will create a local variable "$" which will "hide" the jQuery object in the outer scope.

So `$` will take the role of an event (local `$`) and is a function no more (outer `$`), hence your error.

Just call `function()` with no params, it should do fine.