# How to return a variable with jQuery each function

Tags: jquery, function, variables, return, each

This is my script (simplified):

```
var $error = false;
//Check for errors
$('.required').each(function()
{
    var $error = true;
});
alert($error);
```

How to make the above code return **true** in the alert function?
The each function is executed 3 times at my page to check for empty fields.
But in the above the alert contains **false** instead of **true**.
Is there a way to parse the variable **$error** outside the each function to check if there are empty fields after the each loop?

Comment: If you're been alerted `false`, then you have no elements that match the `.required` selector. Try fixing this first :)

Comment: Related [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373278/variable-shadowing-in-javascript) and [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing).

Comment: Thanks for the article link!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop the `var` inside the `.each()` callback function, otherwise you are defining a new variable in a different scope.

```
var $error = false;
//Check for errors
$('.required').each(function()  //<-- start of new scope block
{
    var $error = true;  //<--defines new variable -- different from one above
});
alert($error);
```

Dropping `var`, it will now use the variable defined in the block above it

```
var $error = false;
//Check for errors
$('.required').each(function()  
{
    $error = true;  
});
alert($error);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are *shadowing* the outer `$error` variable inside the `.each()` callback. Get rid of the `var` so you reference the outer one instead:

```
var $error = false;
$('.required').each(function() {
    $error = true; // Now this refers to the `$error` declared above
});
```

However, if you're simply using the `.each` call to check if any elements have the `.required` class, you could just check `.length`:

```
alert($('.required').length > 0); // true or false depending if elements matched
```

Comment: For more information: [Variable shadowing in Javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter3.html#p14dd0d54)

Comment: Thanks a lot all! Learned something small but very usefull again today! Plus your second way is a lot easier. I will use it. I was now using: $(this).val()=='' instead.

Answer (score 3):

just remove the inner `var` keyword

```
var $error = false;
//Check for errors
$('.required').each(function()
{
     $error = true;  // No Var Here
});
alert($error);
```

or use `window` as your namespace like the following

```
window.error = false;
//Check for errors
$('.required').each(function()
{
     window.error = true;  // No Var Here
});
alert(window.error);
```

Note its better to break the loop if you got an error with `return false` -- just a performance advice !

Answer (score 2):

You `$erro` declared `locally` and `globally`

```
var $error = false;
$('.required').each(function()
{
    $error = true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the texts are empty you can use:

```
var $error = false;
$('input.anyclass').each(function()
{
    if($(this).val() == "")
    {
        $error = true;
    }
});
alert($error);
```