# Jquery Document.ready loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a loop in my document.ready event so that I can have dry code. However the click event returns undefined when I create it via the loop but works fine when I declare each document.ready event singularly.

```
<script>
var $a = jQuery.noConflict();
$a(document).ready(function () {
    $a(".nav-1-1").css('cursor','pointer').click(function(event) {
        window.location.href = $a(".nav-1-1").find("a").attr("href");
    });
});

$a(document).ready(function () {
    $a(".nav-1-2").css('cursor','pointer').click(function(event) {
        window.location.href = $a(".nav-1-2").find("a").attr("href");
    });
});

$a(document).ready(function () {
    $a(".nav-1-3").css('cursor','pointer').click(function(event) {
        window.location.href = $a(".nav-1-3").find("a").attr("href");
    });
});

$a(document).ready(function () {
    $a(".nav-1-4").css('cursor','pointer').click(function(event) {
        window.location.href = $a(".nav-1-4").find("a").attr("href");
    });
});

$a(document).ready(function () {
    $a(".nav-1-5").css('cursor','pointer').click(function(event) {
        window.location.href = $a(".nav-1-5").find("a").attr("href");
    });
});

$a(document).ready(function () {
    $a(".nav-1-6").css('cursor','pointer').click(function(event) {
        window.location.href = $a(".nav-1-6").find("a").attr("href");
    });
});

$a(document).ready(function () {
    $a(".nav-1-7").css('cursor','pointer').click(function(event) {
        window.location.href = $a(".nav-1-7").find("a").attr("href");
    });
});

$a(document).ready(function () {
    $a(".nav-1-8").css('cursor','pointer').click(function(event) {
        window.location.href = $a(".nav-1-8").find("a").attr("href");
    });
});

$a(document).ready(function () {
    $a(".nav-1-9").css('cursor','pointer').click(function(event) {
        window.location.href = $a(".nav-1-9").find("a").attr("href");
    });
});

$a(document).ready(function () {
    $a(".nav-1-10").css('cursor','pointer').click(function(event) {
        window.location.href = $a(".nav-1-10").find("a").attr("href");
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is the loop I am trying to make to simplify the above code:

```
<script>
var $a = jQuery.noConflict();

$a(document).ready(function () {
    for (var i=1; i<11; i++) {
        $a(".nav-1-1"+i).css('cursor','pointer').click(function(event) {
            window.location.href = $a(".nav-1-1").find("a").attr("href");
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

I have corrected the above loop as Trevor pointed out I had forgotten to include the i variable.

Comment: It seems like you are making this way too complex. What does your html look like?

Comment: `$a(".nav-1-1")` You are not making use of `i` in your dry code example `$a(".nav-1-"+i)`

Comment: bažmegakapa - this is jQuery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplifying your logic a bit:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("[class*='nav-1-']").css('cursor', 'pointer').click(function() {
        location = $(this).find("a").prop("href");
    });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/oKExezi/3/edit)

Though, you should consider adding a common class to all `nav-1-XX` elements to select them in an simpler and more efficient manner. If you do that, you can also apply the `cursor:pointer` on that class.

---

### Explanation

`jQuery(fn)` is a shorthand for [`jQuery(document).ready(fn)`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/). This is just a matter of preference. Either of these receive forms' callback receives `jQuery` as the first argument, hence I'm aliasing it back to `$` inside the DOM ready callback. This can be used in `noConflict` mode the same way.

The [Attribute Contains Selector `[name*="value"]`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) will select all elements that contain a `nav-1-` in their class attribute. If you follow my advice and add a common class to all elements, you won't need it.

Inside of a function being called as event handler, the `this` reference will point to the element which has received the event that it is listening to. That is, `this` will reference the given `nav-1-XX` which has been clicked.

Finally, the `window` (global scope) doesn't need to be referenced explicitly. [Lexical scope](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1047454/1331430) will find it either way:

```
window.location === location
```

*(That is, unless you've [shadowed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5373278/1331430) the global location object)*

Hence, using either `window.location` and `location` is mostly a matter of preference.

Assigning to either `location` or `location.href` is a matter of preference as well, since both are widely supported.

Comment: This looks better than what I have however I must alias jQuery to var $a because of conflicts with another javascript framework that is in use. Could you provide an example of this with the var $a?

Comment: @user2958381 see this answer's [first revision](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/19801064/1). Though, as long as you do not need to reference the other library inside this DOM ready handler you should have no problems with the code I've posted in the answer - the `$` alias is local to the function I'm passing in `jQuery(fn)`. You can as well just replace all occurrences of `$` (including the parameter name) to alias it to your liking (e.g. `$a`).

Comment: I tried your above code, but it didn't work. Your revision did. Thank you so very much!

Answer (score 1):

What if you mix php and Js ?! Use php to generate the long code above .. and in your index.php it will still look the same small code :

example:

```
$a(document).ready(function () {

<?php
$i=0;
 while ( $i < 11)
{
$i++;
?>

    $a(".nav-1-<?php echo $i;?>").css('cursor','pointer').click(function(event) {
        window.location.href = $a(".nav-1-<?php echo $i;?>").find("a").attr("href");
    });

<?php
 }
?>

});
```