# I am receiving a message in node.js and the object socket is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I have the following code:

```
function Socket(io, playGame, mapper) {
    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        // message handler for the chat message
        socket.on('sendChat', function (data) {
            console.log(socket);
            console.log(data);
            console.log('recieved chat');

            var connectedPlayer = playGame.findConnectedPlayer(socket);
            if (!connectedPlayer)
                return;

            var connectedGame = playGame.findConnectedGame(socket, connectedPlayer.gameId);
            if (!connectedGame)
                return;

            // send update game with players properly ordered
            for (socketIndex in this.sockets) {
                var socket = this.sockets[socketIndex];

                // send the new data to each player
                socket.socket.emit('chatUpdate', { chatText: data.chat });
            }
        });

        // message handler for join game message
        socket.on('joinGame', function (data) {
            console.log('recieved join:', JSON.stringify(data));

            if (!playGame.newConnectedPlayer(socket, data))
                return;
```

...

In the method for sendChat, socket is undefined. In the method for joinGame, socket is defined. I have tried several ideas, but the problem persists. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure `this.sockets` and `this.sockets[socketIndex]` exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to rename one of the 2 `socket` variables -- either the parameter for `'connection'` or the `var` in the loop:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
```

```
for (socketIndex in this.sockets) {
    var socket = this.sockets[socketIndex];
```

The `var` is [shadowing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373278/variable-shadowing-in-javascript) the parameter, rendering the parameter inaccessible.

This happens in part because the `var socket` doesn't only exist within the `for` loop. JavaScript `var`s are `function`-scoped and their declarations are [hoisted](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html) to the top of the `function`, as in:

```
socket.on('sendChat', function (data) {
    var connectedPlayer, connectedGame, socket; // each initially `undefined`

    console.log(socket);

    // ...

    for (socketIndex in this.sockets) {
        socket = this.sockets[socketIndex];

    // ...
});
```

And, having the same exact name, at most only one of them can be reached from a particular `function`.

---

Also note that the `for` loop and `var socket` aren't really necessary.

You can use the Socket.IO `Server`'s [own `.emit()` method](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#server#emit) to send a message to all clients.

```
io.emit('chatUpdate', { chatText: data.chat });
```