# Promise is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm trying to use a promise but get a type error: Promise is not a constructor.

Here's the promise:

```
        var Promise = new Promise(
            function (resolve,error) {
                for (var key in excludeValues) {
                   /* some ifs */
                    minVal = someValue 
                    ........
                    ........
                    }


                resolve(errors)
            });
            Promise.then(
            function(data){
                if (minVal > maxVal)
                {
                    errors.minMax.push(
                        'minMax'
                    )
                }

                if (gapVal > minVal * -1)
                {
                    errors.minMax.push(
                        'gapVal'
                    )
                }
                return (errors.minMax.length == 0 && errors.zahl.length == 0 && errors.hoch.length == 0 && errors.niedrig.length == 0)
            }
        );
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Trying to name something the same thing as a another thing seems like a bad idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `var Promise` you declare a local variable in your scope. It is initialised with `undefined` and [shadows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5373278/1048572) the global `Promise` constructor. Use a different variable name

```
var promise = new Promise(…);
promise.then(…);
```

or none at all

```
new Promise(…).then(…);
```

Answer (score 0):

problem is you are overwriting Promise function, so when you execute code second time "Promise" is not function anymore.

so change variable name as shown below

```
var promisevariable = new Promise(
        function (resolve,error) {
            for (var key in excludeValues) {
               /* some ifs */
                minVal = someValue 
                ........
                ........
                }


            resolve(errors)
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem that gives an almost identical error message. I declared:

`var promise = new promise (...)` instead of `new Promise(...)`.

That mistake will give a very similar error message, as follows:

`promise is not a constructor` (note the *lowercase* `promise`).

In this case, the error is because you're referencing the variable you've declared (`promise`), instead of invoking the `Promise` constructor.