# Unit testing with Jasmine, mocking a constructor

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm unit testing JavaScript with Jasmine and I am running into some problems.

I have a large file to test and it has a lot of dependencies and those dependencies have their own dependencies. Because of said dependencies I want to mock all I can. There lies the problem. How can I mock a constructor so that it includes the methods that belong to it?

Lets say I'm testing a method `createMap` of class `Map`:

In that `createMap` method it calls for `Layers` class constructor using

```
var layers = new Layers()
```

I'm spying on it using

```
spyOn(window, 'Layers').and.callThrough()
```

That works fine but later in the `createMap` method it calls for `layers.addLayer()` where `addLayer` is a method of `Layers` class. Problem is that because I mocked the `Layers` call it doesn't recognize the `addLayer` method.

Is there a way to mock it so that it includes all the methods of the called class or is my only option to stub the whole `Layers` class or not mock it?

Or what would be a good way to handle this? I've tried to `spyOn(Layers, 'addLayer')` but there it says that no method `addLayer` is found.

I'm sorry if it's confusing a bit. I had trouble thinking how should I ask it.

Comment: Either use Dependency Injection or use the Rewire module.

Comment: @limelights could you explain a little bit more about Rewire module?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IMO, it's unnecessary to spy on `window`, since you can easily [shadow the  variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5373899/1092711) in local scope by creating a spy object with the same name:

```
describe('Map', function () {
    var Layers;

    beforeEach(function () {
        Layers = function () {
            // alternatively, you could move this to Layers.prototype
            this.addLayers = jasmine.createSpy('Layers#addLayers');
        };
    });

    /* ... */
});
```

If you want an automatic mocking and using CommonJS modules, you may try [Jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/automatic-mocking.html) framework, which is built on top of Jasmine.

Comment: This might sound like a stupid follow up question but if I use this method wouldn't the createMap method call `var layers = new Layers()` and it would fail as it's an object and not a function/constructor.

Comment: @MikeJones you're right, it needs to be a function. See updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let's talk in terms of example classes you have provided.

You're writing a test suite for `Map`. All its dependencies (in example we have only `Layer`) MUST be mocked. Because in a unit test you're supposed to test one layer, as small functionality as possible. It means that you should provide such a mocked `Layer` constructor that exposes interface used in `Map`. For example:

```
function Layers() {
    this.addLayer = sinon.spy();
}
```

In this test suite only `Map` class should remain "real". I.e. it's code must not be altered. And with such mockups like `Layer` you make sure that you do not trigger any interaction with real-code dependencies (own-written dependencies should be tested in a different test suite, also make sure you don't try to test framework functions, like `$tate.resolve`, `$inject` etc.). If class `Map` is complicated and has multiple dependencies, investigate sinon features that help automate this process, for example [`sinon.mock`](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#mocks)

Answer (score 1):

If you ever transpile class syntax to a es3 or another pre-2015 dialect you will discover something interesting.

```
class a {
    constructor(){
        ...
    }
    
    index()
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

Becomes:

```
var a = /** @class */ (function () {
    function a() {
        ...
    }
    a.prototype.index = function () {
       ...
    };
    return a;
}());
```

This same implementation is used by later standards but masked by the 2015 class syntax. In other words `a.index` doesn't exist instead it's defined as `a.prototype.index`. Thus you need `spyOn(a.prototype, 'index')` to spy on it.

Change `spyOn(Layers, 'addLayer')` to `spyOn(Layers.prototype, 'addLayer')`