# Start interval through timeout

Tags: jquery, settimeout, setinterval, clearinterval, cleartimeout

I have this piece of code that initially starts an interval. Then with the push of a button, I want that interval to be stopped/cleared, wait X seconds, and then start the interval again.

This code starts the interval and works fine:

```
var timeout = undefined;
var interval = setInterval(bgScroll, timeBetweenSwap);
```

Then I want the interval to be stopped when i click the button, let it wait X seconds and start again (ofcourse pressing the button again should reset that amount of seconds)

```
$(document).on('click', '.bgscroller a', function(){
    clearInterval(interval);
    clearTimeout(timeout);

    var timeout = setTimeout(function(){
        var interval = setInterval(bgScroll, timeBetweenSwap);
    }, delayAfterClick);
});
```

Now when i click the button a few times the interval goes crazy and stacks up. I would suggest it to be cleared... any advice oh how I should fix this?

Kind regards,
Narayan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, remove the last two `var` statements. Make it `timeout =` and `interval =` instead of `var timeout =` and `var interval =`.

Your code is really close—it looks like you're [shadowing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373278/variable-shadowing-in-javascript) the `timeout` and `interval` variables on the last few lines.

This is the bit that's wrong:

```
var timeout = setTimeout(function(){
    var interval = setInterval(bgScroll, timeBetweenSwap);
}, delayAfterClick);
```

It should look like this (very similar):

```
timeout = setTimeout(function(){
    interval = setInterval(bgScroll, timeBetweenSwap);
}, delayAfterClick);
```

Note that we removed the `var` statements. This uses the same `timeout` and `interval` variables like above, rather than making new variables that happen to have the same names.

Comment: 1+ For mentioning shadowing

Comment: Thank you so much Evan..! You have no idea how much time I've wasted on searching for answers :(