# Javascript Onclick Function Only Works Once

Tags: javascript, html

I have a hopefully pretty easy problem.  I'm trying to create a JS function on my app where there's a number in HTML and every time it is clicked, another number is subtracted from it and the result displays.

(So far this much works.)

Then the action *should* be repeatable so the number keeps getting smaller.

(This part doesn't work yet.)

Finally, there's a reset button that, when clicked, resets the original number to a random number.

(The random number is found correctly, but when you click to subtract it subtracts from the original number, not from the randomly-chosen replacement number.)

Here's a partially-working JSFiddle

```js
var s = document.getElementById('incrimentOfNumber').innerHTML
 var n = document.getElementById('countdownNumber').innerHTML
 var n = n - s;

 document.getElementById("countdownNumber").onclick = function updateNumber(){
  this.innerHTML = n;
 }

 document.getElementById("resetCountdown").onclick = function resetCountdown(){
  var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + 200;
  document.getElementById("countdownNumber").innerHTML = n;
 }
```

```html
    <h3>Count down from the number you see in incriments of <span class="incrimentOfNumber" id="incrimentOfNumber">7</span>.
     <br />Tap the number to see the correct answer.
     <br />Repeat as needed.
 </h3>

    <div class="countdownNumber">
     <h1 id="countdownNumber">284</h1>
 </div>

    <div class="btn" id="resetCountdown">Reset</div>
```

Can anyone (1) double check what I've done to make sure I'm not doing things in a stupid way and (2) help me figure out how to get the repeatable action functioning?

Comment: Ahhh, throwback to a discarded approach.  Will edit the OP.

Comment: `this.innerHTML = n` is assigning exactly the same `n` that is calculated _once_ when the page is loaded at `var n = n - s;`. That `n` never changes again. The `var n` in the second listener is a completely different `n` that is scoped to only that second function. The event listeners are working fine. That code also isn’t subtracting anything.

Comment: I tried putting `var n = n - s` inside the `updateNumber` function, but it just turned it to `undefined`...

Comment: Put that line in the function, but remove the `var`. Everytime you use `var` in front of a variable, you scope it to the function, meaning that it’s not the same variable as the outside one anymore. If you remove `var`, you actually refer to the outside variable. See [Surprised that global variable has undefined value in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9085839/4642212).

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you!

Comment: Another reference that’s even closer to your issue: [On click function add number to variable - gives NaN](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42441315/4642212).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you are calculating value of n only once, it should be calculated on every click thus change you countdown click function to:

```
document.getElementById("countdownNumber").onclick = function updateNumber(){
        var s = document.getElementById('incrimentOfNumber').innerHTML
        var n = document.getElementById('countdownNumber').innerHTML
        n = n - s;
        this.innerHTML = n;
}
```

Here is a working demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/m3q8fn2x/

Answer (score 1):

If you are still struggling with this ,then consider the fact that when you declare a variable inside an event function its starting value is always the same , when the event is triggered. So consider this fact and declare variables outside the event function's scope.

```
const togglerBtn = document.getElementById("togglerBtn");

let temp = false;
togglerBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
//   alert();

if (!temp) {
  togglerDiv.style.transform = "translateY(48px)";
  return (temp = true);
} else if (temp) {
  togglerDiv.style.transform = "translateY(-500px)";
  return (temp = false);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your working code:

You need to put the `n = n - s` part into the update number function so its called each time you click.

```js
var s = document.getElementById('incrimentOfNumber').innerHTML
var n = document.getElementById('countdownNumber').innerHTML

document.getElementById("countdownNumber").onclick = function updateNumber() {
    n = n - s;
    this.innerHTML = n;
}

document.getElementById("resetCountdown").onclick = function resetCountdown(){
    n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + 200;
    document.getElementById("countdownNumber").innerHTML = n;
}
```

```html
    <h3>Count down from the number you see in incriments of <span class="incrimentOfNumber" id="incrimentOfNumber">7</span>.
     <br />Tap the number to see the correct answer.
     <br />Repeat as needed.
 </h3>

    <div class="countdownNumber">
     <h1 id="countdownNumber">284</h1>
 </div>

    <div class="btn" id="resetCountdown">Reset</div>
```

Comment: While this is a nice solution, it lacks the explanation.