# Uncaught TypeError when invoking callbacks

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, onreadystatechange

I had an error that I have managed to fix on my own. Can someone please explain to me why my code wasn’t working and the mechanics of what caused it.

Code is included below:

```
var listTables = function (tables) {
  console.log(tables);
}

var ajaxReq = function (success_cb, url) {
  // success_cb can be invoked here without errors
  var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  http.onreadystatechange = function (success_cb) {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      success_cb(this); // Uncaught TypeError: success_cb is not a function
    }
  }
  http.open("GET", url, true);
  http.send();
}
ajaxReq(listTables, "http://www.someurl.com");
```

When I remove the `success_cb` callback from the `onreadystatechange` function definition the code works fine. Is this an issue that is related to scope?

Comment: You don’t need to repeat `success_cb` as a parameter in the inner function. Doing so will overwrite the original `success_cb` by the event argument of the `readystatechange` event.

Comment: Can you show how you’re using ajaxReq

Comment: @Xufox no I don’t. Not at my computer atm so using my phone. Hence the crappy formatting.

Comment: @MattSugden corrected. Have a look now.

Comment: if this really fixed your code then it's undoubtedly a matter of scope. You would need to post the actual full code to verify.

Comment: @Xufox does this mean that readystatechange function cannot access the listTables() function?

Comment: @Courtney It can access `listTables`, since it’s accessible from where it’s scoped, but it cannot access the _original_ `success_cb` since you provide a _second, different_ `success_cb` which is _scoped closer than the first one_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is that you repeated `success_cb` as a parameter in the *inner* function:

```
var ajaxReq = function (success_cb, url) { // First time success_cb parameter is used: correct.
  var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  http.onreadystatechange = function (success_cb) { // Second time: wrong!
    // ...
  }
  // ...
}
```

This does two unintended things:

- it overshadows your original (first) `success_cb`, so it’s not accessible anymore
- it instead assigns the *event argument* of the `readystatechange` event to `success_cb` which is an object

“[Overshadowing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5373278/4642212)” means, that a variable (or parameter) of the same name is provided that is scoped *closer* than the previous one.

So just remove the second usage:

```
var listTables = function (tables) {
  console.log(tables);
}

var ajaxReq = function (success_cb, url) {
  // success_cb can be invoked here without errors
  var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  http.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      success_cb(this);
    }
  }
  http.open("GET", url, true);
  http.send();
}
ajaxReq(listTables, "http://www.someurl.com");
```