# Why are changes to an array (passed in as param) maintained outside the function in one case, in the other not?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, pass-by-reference

I've recently learned about pass-by-reference. So I expected the behaviour of arr2, but have trouble understanding why arr1 is not changed outside of the function. Someone please enlighten me?

```js
let arr1 = ([1, 2, 3, 4])
let arr2;
let a = 1
let b = 3
filterRange(arr1, a, b);

function filterRange(arr1, a, b) {
  arr2 = arr1.filter(item => {
     return ((item >= a) && (item <= b)) ? item : "";
  });
  arr1 = arr1.filter(item => {
     return ((item >= a) && (item <= b)) ? item : "";
  });
  return
}

console.log(arr1) // [1, 2, 3, 4]
console.log(arr2) // [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: You've created a variable `arr1` inside the function. This is [variable shadowing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373278/what-is-the-correct-term-for-variable-shadowing-in-javascript)

Comment: *"why arr1 is not changed outside of the function"* Because \JavaScript doesn't use pass-by-reference, it uses pass-by-value, so you would never get the behavior you expect.

Comment: @evolutionxbox: That's not relevant in this case. OP expects that assigning to a parameter changes the outer variable. The name of the parameter doesn't matter.

Comment: @FelixKling sure. I still think it's worth noting. Even if in this case it's not the primary issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's all clear to me now!